# What tools to use for remote development? (C++,Ubuntu, ssh)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, c++, ssh

I'm currently tasked with doing some C++/CUDA development on a remote Linux machine from another Linux machine, connected via ssh. I've primarily been using Windows which makes things difficult (terminal is still a scary black box for me). Previously I was using X2go from a Windows machine, so I had a graphical user interface and everything was fine, but now I feel totally lost.

Specifically, I was looking for some IDE that supports custom CMakeLists projects, but if there are different methods and tools I'm eager to learn them. My main problem is that I don't even know what tools I should learn. Also I'm a little afraid of using more powerful tools because I don't have much confidence in my being able to properly configure them.

It would be nice if you could tell me what kind of tools you are using for this kind of task and why (and maybe why you would recommend it specifically for someone with my background).

Originally from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112554/what-tools-to-use-for-remote-development-c-ubuntu-ssh?noredirect=1#comment42728230_27112554

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org) along with the [uniwin plugin](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Installing_Uniwin_remote_compiler) to allow your remote building.  You can also set-up the debugger to work with either [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) in [remote mode](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Remote-Debugging.html#Remote-Debugging) or using [GdbServer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gdbserver).

- Free tool chain.
- Can be set up for other tool chains.
- Code Completion.
- GUI debugger - even in remote modes.

You can also do similar things from within:
Codelite, Dev-C++, Geany, GNAT Programming Studio (GPS), KDevelop, Qt Creator, Lazarus, MonoDevelop, Eclipse, NetBeans but I personally have only used Code::Blocks and Eclipse in this way and the Eclipse set-up I find a lot more complex unless preconfigured by an embedded OS manufacturer, e.g. QNX Monumetrics.

Comment: Thanks, in the end, I ended up using Eclipse Nvidia Nsight version.

Answer (score 0):

My answer in the end was to use the Nvidia Nsight edition Eclipse. Even for a novice like myself, it was not too difficult to set everything up including the remote part. The editors added 'knowledge' of CUDA also adds a few points in terms of comfort.

I haven't tried this yet but this IDE also allows you to set breakpoints in CUDA code. I think this will be very handy at times.